# How to convert LocalDate to SQL Date Java?

Tags: java, java-8, converters, java-time, sqldatetime

How do I convert a LocalDate to a `java.sql.Date`?

Attempt:

```
Record r = new Record();
LocalDate date = new Date(1967, 06, 22);
r.setDateOfBirth(new Date(date));
```

This fails *(won't compile)* and all I can find is Joda time stuff.

I'm using Java 8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert between LocalDate and sql.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750861/convert-between-localdate-and-sql-date)

Comment: @assylias How is the answer on the linked question any better than the ones given here? The other question should be closed as a duplicate of this, not vice versa.

Comment: @SecondRikudo the duplicate shows how to convert from LocalDate to Date AND vice versa, and therefore seems more general.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

The answer is really simple;

```
import java.sql.Date;
...
LocalDate locald = LocalDate.of(1967, 06, 22);
Date date = Date.valueOf(locald); // Magic happens here!
r.setDateOfBirth(date);
```

If you would want to convert it the other way around, you do it like this:

```
Date date = r.getDate();
LocalDate localD = date.toLocalDate();
```

`r` is the record you're using in JOOQ and `.getDate()` is the method for getting the date out of your record; let's say you have a date column called date_of_birth, then your get method should be called `getDateOfBirth()`.

Comment: This is a "horrible hack" according with the java.time.* author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066904/localdate-to-java-util-date-and-vice-versa-simplest-conversion#comment72769769_33066935

Comment: You're reffering to questions about `java.util.Date` **NOT** `java.sql.Date` which this Question is about.

Answer (score 0):

If you want current date:

```
Date date = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
```

If you want a specific date:

```
Date date = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(1967, 06, 22));
```

Comment: This is only faster if you want the current moment, if you want a specific date, as might be the case when you're dealing with someone's date of birth this won't work at all.

Comment: Yes, it's to insert current date, for example when you create object and want to persist creation date.

Comment: Which is important to note as the original question is all about creating a specific date. It's a note for all the copy-pasters out there.
You CAN oneline the correct answer with `Date date = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(1967, 06, 22));` if you want to do it "faster".

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using the toDate() method of LocalDate?

As in:

```
Record r = new Record();
LocalDate date = new Date(1967, 06, 22);
r.setDateOfBirth(date.toDate());
```

In general, it is a good idea to specify *how* it fails rather than just say "it fails".

Comment: To be honest, I only posted the question to post my answer so that you can find it when you google. I had to figure it on my own because goodle didn't have this question or answer.

Comment: Well, now you have two answers then, the more the merrier. I don't think there is anything wrong in answering your own posts.

Comment: I hope it will help someone in my place in the future.

Comment: The OP wrote “[…] all I can find is Joda time stuff. I'm unsing Java 8”. Your answer, however, is just more Joda stuff instead of a Java 8 answer.

Comment: `getDate()` is deprecated since Java 1.1

Comment: LocalDate.toDate() exists only in the Joda version of LocalDate, not in the standard library version.