# Convert java.sql.date to java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: java

How do I convert a `java.sql.Date` returned from a JDBC database to a `java.time.LocalDateTime`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert between LocalDate and sql.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750861/convert-between-localdate-and-sql-date)

Comment: I already looked at that question. But I'm trying to convert an sql.Date to a LocalDateTime and not a LocalDate.

Comment: Then the answer linked by @nobody can help (duplicate): [Converting between java.time.LocalDateTime and java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date). `java.sql.Date` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`, so you can cast it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It was actually easier than I thought.
This worked for me:

```
//java.sql.ResultSet result
result.getTimestamp("value").toLocalDateTime()
```

Comment: This is a plausible answer and correct for <= Java 7, but you can skip transformations using the `hibernate-java8` library. Might be a better way nowadays.

Comment: It is not only plausible, but correct and simplistic. However, LocalDateTime was in fact introduced in 1.8 (Java 8).

Conversion to the joda-time precursor that used to be de facto standard (external) time library in earlier versions of Java was made on the receiving end, such as by use of the DateTime constructor.

Comment: What object type does the result here refer to? (There is no getTimestamp() method on java.sql.Date.)

Comment: I don't have the code in question anymore but I assume java.sql.ResultSet https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Answer (score 1):

Working method:

```
public LocalDate convertToLocalDateViaMilisecond(Date dateToConvert) {
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateToConvert.getTime())
      .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
      .toLocalDate();
}
```

Non-working build for java.sql.Date (because it throws UnsupportedOperationException for instant() method):

```
public LocalDate convertToLocalDateViaInstant(Date dateToConvert) {
    return dateToConvert.toInstant()
      .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
      .toLocalDate();
}
```

Credits to [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-to-localdate-and-localdatetime) for this answer on his site:

Comment: if (date instanceof java.sql.Date)
            date = new Date(date.getTime());

Answer (score -1):

A possible way is to first convert it to java.time.LocalDate and then to java.time.LocalDateTime

```
sqlDate.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay()
```

Also you can specify a specific time using atTime() function

```
sqlDate.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(hour, miniute, second)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Java 8 and Hibernate 5 there is no need of converting from/to java.sql.Date, only trust on Java's magic.

The dependency you need to use is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

In case you are using spring-boot there is no need to declare any extra dependency.

If you are using a previous version of Java the recommendation is to define a Converter like this one:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

  @Override
  public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
    return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
  }

  @Override
  public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
    return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
  }
}
```

You can found more about the use of LocalDateTime in Java 8 in this [link](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/), and more about this kind of converters on this [link](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/).

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question, but rather a suggestion of addition of a third party dependency.

Comment: @Martin, not necessarily, if you are using spring-boot you don't need new dependencies. And probably you need to question yourself if it's correct to use plain jdbc directly instead of jpa

Comment: Yeesh. This still isn't an answer to the question, but rather religion. There are several options to JPA, and sometimes JDBC without much abstraction is in fact superior to pulling heavy dependencies like Hibernate, regardless if they are implicitly or explicitly declared. I'm not the one to judge, but a question should be answered in its own context, not filtered by personal preference.

Answers like these do not help the community understanding code, and especially not phrasings like "only trust on Java's magic".

Comment: Dear @Martin, I've read your reply only today, but thank you, you have expressed with few words my position about some Java "developers" that I've encountered in these years