# How to stop LocalDate from changing when being saved to a mySQL database

Tags: mysql, java-8, jpa-2.0, hibernate-5.x, localdate

When saving a `LocalDate` field (e.g. '2017-09-27') to a mySQL `Date` column using JPA CriteriaBuilder API, the result is different (e.g. '2017-09-26').

I have validated that my database's timezone is set to UTC using `SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP)` as the result is '00:00:00'.

I am testing this locally, and I have a timezone of GMT + 2, so my suspicion is that when the conversion occurs from `LocalDate` to `Date`, 2 hours are being deducted and producing a date 1 day before the requested date (assuming that the `LocalDate` field, as a result of it having **no** time information, is being treated as 00:00:00.

What is the best way to save LocalDates in this situation? Should I be following the advice here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751575/3832047 and explicitly setting all LocalDate fields to UTC or something similar?

I ran a test to see what happens when converting them in code and got the following result:

```
Date convertedDate = Date.valueOf(localDate);
```

[conversion-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDbH6.png)

EDIT

Here is an example of the code I use to retrieve the data, where the odd date change occurs as well. If I request data for `2017-06-27`, I receive results for `2017-06-26`.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = sessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(HorseAndTrailerRequest.class);
Root<HorseAndTrailerRequest> criteria = criteriaQuery.from(HorseAndTrailerRequest.class);

ParameterExpression<LocalDate> effectiveDateParameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(LocalDate.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(criteria)
            .where(
                    criteriaBuilder.equal(criteria.get("effectiveDate"), effectiveDateParameter)
            );

TypedQuery<HorseAndTrailerRequest> query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
query.setParameter(effectiveDateParameter, date);
return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Java `LocalDate` objects store no time or timezone information (see [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)], I suspect something else.

Comment: Can you try running the following to confirm your MySQL server timezone: `SELECT  @@system_time_zone, NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The result is `UTC | 2017-09-27 11:28:51 | 2017-09-27 11:28:51`.

Comment: I upvoted your question, but at this point I think we need to see the Java code which is saving the local dates into your MySQL.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's occurring on reads as well - when doing a query requesting data from `2017-09-27' I'm receiving data from '2017-09-26' only, very odd behaviour. I'll edit the question with an example read.

Answer (score 2):

Since `LocalDate` has no TimeZone, you can map the column_date as long in your database schema, and use `AttributeConverter` to convert `LocalDate` to long to avoid time zone conversion problems :

```
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
@Converter
public class LocalDateToLong implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Long> {

    @Override
    public Long convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate date) {
        if (date != null) {
            long epochDay = date.toEpochDay();
            return epochDay;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Long epochDay) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (epochDay != null) {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(epochDay);
            return date;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved it seeing the hibernate atlassian issues ( here is the thread: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11396) . You have two alternatives:

1. Setting the JVM using `-Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin` or programmatically by `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));`
2. Creating a zoned DateTime and then converting it back to Date

   ```
   public static final ZoneId ZONE_EUROPE_BERLIN = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");

   @Override
   public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
       if (locDate == null) {
           return null;
       }

       ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = locDate.atStartOfDay(ZONE_EUROPE_BERLIN);
       LocalDate producerLocalDate = zonedDateTime.toLocalDate();
       Date date = Date.valueOf(producerLocalDate);

       return date;
   }
   ```

I used the second alternative.