# java program to add validation for DOB and phone number which is taken from user and stored in mysql via jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am creating a application using Java AND JDBC in eclipse IDE to insert user details like `name`, `userId`, `DOB`, `Address`, `Phone number`, etc, taken dynamically and to store in database table and then fetch it.
For date-of-birth (DOB) and phone number fields, I have to add validation, i.e. DOB should be between 2000-01-01 and 1940-01-01 and phone number should be exactly 10 digits.

this is the query used to create table--> String q = "create table UserDetails1 (userid int(20),name varchar(100),DOB DATE, address varchar(300),phone BIGINT, UserRole varchar(20)) " ;

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code I have done so far

```java
public class UserData {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int option = 0;
        do {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase", "root", "root");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Select from the following options to interact with the user data :" + '\n');
            System.out.println("1. Insert user data in database");
            System.out.println("2. Display all users data");
            System.out.println("3. Delete specific user by Userid");
            System.out.println("4. Display specific user data as per their Userid");
            System.out.println("5. Exit " + '\n');
            option = sc.nextInt();
            switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    String y = " insert into UserDetails(userid,name,DOB,address,phone,UserRole) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement st1 = con.prepareStatement(y);
                    System.out.println("Enter Userid");
                    int id1 = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter name");
                    String name1 = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter DOB in YYYY-MM-DD format");
                    String dateOfBirth = sc.next();
                    Date date1 = Date.valueOf(dateOfBirth);
                    sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter address ");
                    String address1 = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter 10 digit phone number");
                    double phone1 = sc.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter user role:");
                    String userrole1 = sc.next();
                    st1.setInt(1, id1);
                    st1.setString(2, name1);
                    st1.setDate(3, date1);
                    st1.setString(4, address1);
                    st1.setDouble(5, phone1);
                    st1.setString(6, userrole1);
                    st1.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("data inserted");
                    con.close();
                    break;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Exiting...." + '\n');
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println('\n' + "Choose from the available options..! " + '\n');
            }
        } while (option != 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: well you could instantiate 2000-01-01 and than 1940-01-01 as dates and upon getting date from user, compare it to the two dates, and if it is not in between break. Check if length of phone number == 10, if not break.

Comment: Do not use `Date`. That class is outdated and was replaced because it was poorly designed. Use `LocalDate` for a date of birth (since Java 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some general comments regarding your code.

```java
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
```

This is [no longer needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220724/class-fornamejdbc-driver-no-longer-needed).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

The only [checked exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) that method `main` throws is [SQLException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/SQLException.html) so you should change `Exception` (in the above code line) to `SQLException`.

You should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and subsequently remove this line:

```java
con.close();
```

Create the `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` and `Scanner` outside of the `do-while` loop since you only need to create each of them once only and not repeatedly in every loop iteration.

After calling method `nextInt()` – and before calling `next()` – you need to call `nextLine()`. Refer to [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo). I suggest `nextLine()` together with `Integer.parseInt()`. Also, in my opinion, better to call method `nextLine()` rather than method `next()`.

Now to your specific questions.

Variable `phone1` should have type `long` and not type `int` since `int` cannot store the largest, possible, ten digit number. However phone numbers can have leading zeros. Since the data type of column `phone` in database table `UserDetails` is `BIGINT`, then, according to MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html), that database data type maps to [Java] `long`. Therefore phone number cannot have leading zeros so checking the value entered by the user is done using a simple `if`:

```java
if (phone1 < 1000000000L  ||  phone1 > 9999999999L)
```

In order to check date-of-birth (DOB), I suggest using [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). Note that `java.sql.Date` contains both a date and a time and a time-zone. However, I assume that DOB is just a date without a time and hence the time-zone is not relevant. Therefore, you can convert `java.sql.Date` to `LocalDate` and call appropriate methods to determine if the entered date is within the valid range.

```java
System.out.print("Enter DOB in YYYY-MM-DD format: ");
String dateOfBirth = sc.nextLine();
Date date1 = Date.valueOf(dateOfBirth);
LocalDate ld = date1.toLocalDate();
if (ld.isBefore(LocalDate.of(1940, 1, 1)) || ld.isAfter(LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1))) {
    // Invalid DOB
}
```

Refer to [Convert between LocalDate and sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750861/convert-between-localdate-and-sql-date)

Here is my rewrite of your code. Note that it uses [text blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/text-blocks/index.html) which were added in Java 15.

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserData {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        LocalDate minDob = LocalDate.of(1940, 1, 1);
        LocalDate maxDob = LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sql = """
                insert into UserDetails (userid, name, DOB, address, phone, UserRole)
                values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                """;
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase",
                                                          "root",
                                                          "root");
             PreparedStatement st1 = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            int option = 0;
            do {
                System.out.println("Select from the following options to interact with the user data :" + '\n');
                System.out.println("1. Insert user data in database");
                System.out.println("2. Display all users data");
                System.out.println("3. Delete specific user by Userid");
                System.out.println("4. Display specific user data as per their Userid");
                System.out.println("5. Exit " + '\n');
                option = sc.nextInt();
                switch (option) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.print("Enter Userid: ");
                        int id1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
                        String name1 = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter DOB in YYYY-MM-DD format: ");
                        String dateOfBirth = sc.nextLine();
                        Date date1 = Date.valueOf(dateOfBirth);
                        LocalDate ld = date1.toLocalDate();
                        if (ld.isBefore(minDob)  ||  ld.isAfter(maxDob)) {
                            System.out.printf("Not between %s and %s%n", minDob, maxDob);
                            break;
                        }
                        System.out.print("Enter address: ");
                        String address1 = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter 10 digit phone number: ");
                        long phone1 = Long.parseLong(sc.nextLine());
                        if (phone1 < 1000000000L  ||  phone1 > 9999999999L) {
                            System.out.println("Not ten digits.");
                            break;
                        }
                        System.out.print("Enter user role: ");
                        String userrole1 = sc.nextLine();
                        st1.setInt(1, id1);
                        st1.setString(2, name1);
                        st1.setDate(3, date1);
                        st1.setString(4, address1);
                        st1.setLong(5, phone1);
                        st1.setString(6, userrole1);
                        st1.executeUpdate();
                        System.out.println("data inserted");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                        System.out.println("Exiting...." + '\n');
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println('\n' + "Choose from the available options..! " + '\n');
                }
            } while (option != 5);
        }
    }
}
```