# Inserting LocalDate to SQLite database

Tags: java, sql, database

I wrote a simple program which creates table and allow to insert text and date to database. I found here [How to convert LocalDate to SQL Date Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168494/how-to-convert-localdate-to-sql-date-java) how to convert LocalDate to SQL Date format. But after inserting the date to database it is 694220400000 (UNIX time?) instead of 1992-01-01. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Or in SQLite it won't work and I have to convert it to String?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Connection conn = null;
        LocalDate date;
        Statement stmt = null;
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Test.db");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Connected to Database");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("No JDBC driver");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error during connecting");
        }

        String createTest = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'text' TEXT, 'date' Date)";
        try {
            stmt.execute(createTest);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error during creating table");
        }

        date = LocalDate.of(1992, 1, 1);
        Date dat = Date.valueOf(date);
        System.out.println(dat);

        String query = "insert into test values(NULL, ?, ?)";
        System.out.println("Type text");
        String text = input.nextLine();

        try {
            prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            prepStmt.setString(1, text);
            prepStmt.setDate(2, dat);
            prepStmt.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }

        input.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

DATE is an alias for integer. Define 'date' of type TEXT to get an readable date (ISO8601)

https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html