# Extracting date from timestamp in HQL for comparison in a where clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I want to extract (year, month, dayOfMonth) from a timestamp field using HQL for comparison in a where clause.

Example:

```
Query hibernateQuery = session.createQuery("select sum(t.amount) from Transaction t " + 
  "where extract_date(t.timestampField) = :date");

hibernateQuery.setParameter("date", LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 11));

System.out.println( hibernateQuery.getSingleResult() );
```

So I am looking for a function like this pseudo function `extract_date(t.timestampField)` that I've used in example above.

Comment: What is the type of timestampField column?

Comment: @Vivek it is `java.time.LocalDateTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work properly

```
Query hibernateQuery = session.createQuery("select sum(t.amount) from Transaction t " + 
      "where DATE(t.timestampField) = :date");

hibernateQuery.setParameter("date", new java.sql.Date.valueOf("2018-10-11"));
```

**Note:** the data type returned by `DATE(...)` function is `java.sql.Date` so if you are having a `java.time.LocalDate` it can be easily converted to `java.sql.Date` as follow:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 11);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);
```

It is discussed in the following Q/A.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29168526/7972796