# Typeconverter for LocalDate and sql Date in Kotlin doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, date, kotlin, localdate

I'm trying to write a simple typeconverter to map a LocalDate to an sql Date in my room database. I simply followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168494/how-to-convert-localdate-to-sql-date-java) simple answer, and that's my code:

```
import androidx.room.TypeConverter
import java.sql.Date
import java.sql.Date.valueOf
import java.time.LocalDate

class LocalDateTypeConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToLocalDate(dateSql: Date?): LocalDate? {
        return dateSql.toLocalDate()
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun localDateToDate(date: LocalDate?): Date? {
        return valueOf(date)
    }
}
```

It should work, but it doesn't. toLocalDate is shown as unresolved reference, while valueOf seems to require a string instead of a localDate. I'm pretty confused. What i already tried was:

- Set the jvm version to 1.8 for Kotlin,
- Rebuild/clean/invalidate cache

I'm probably missing something, but i can't figure out what!

Comment: Which is your Android API level/minSDK? Does this answer your question? [cannot resolve symbol 'java.time.LocalDate' error in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745205/cannot-resolve-symbol-java-time-localdate-error-in-android-studio)

Comment: Sadly, no. My minsdk is 27 currently, and i set both kotlin and java to 1.8. But i did another mistake: as far as i can see, SQLite (and Room consequently) doesn't support any date type. So i'm trying to convert my date in another incompatible type.