# How do I get java.util.Date from string input to compare to SQL DATE type in InnoDB?

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, innodb

I have a `SQL column` of the nature

```
 `x_date` DATE default null,
```

… in [InnoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB).

Then my `entity class` is

```
@Entity
@Table
public class MyEntity{
//omitted codes

@Column(name="x_date")
private java.util.Date theDate;

//Omitted assessor 

}
```

Now I have a `Controller class` defined like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data")
public class SomeController{

@Autowired
private TheDao dao;

@GetMapping
public List<MyEntity>getByDate(@RequestParam("date")String date){

//How do I get a java util.Date type from the date param to pass to this method?
return dao.findByTheDate(...){
}


}
```

How do I generate a `Date` from a user's input like `http://localhost:8080/data?date=2001-07-14`?

The `jpa repo` is

```
public interface TheDao extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer>{

List<MyEntity>findByTheDate(Date date)
}
 
}
```

I've changed all `Date` types to `LocalDate` in my classes and `interface` and the `controller` class has this declaration

```
LocalDate loc=LocalDate.parse(date);

return dao.findByTheDate(loc);
```

But when I made a `GET` call to `http://localhost:8080/data?date=2019-03-29` I got this `stacktrace`

```
Parameter value [%2019-03-29%] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDate n/a)]...
```

Comment: What database engine? The data types vary radically between database engines.

Comment: `java.util.Date` represents a date with time of day as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. `java.sql.Date` *pretends* to represent a date only, but actually contains a time and offset. These classes are a terrible mess. They were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. For date only, use `LocalDate`.

Comment: @BasilBourque Engine is `InnoDB`

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead as @BasilBourque already said use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. I'll refactor

Comment: Those details such as database engine belong in your Question, not Comments. I added mentions in title, body, and tags this time around.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168494/how-to-convert-localdate-to-sql-date-java

Comment: This seems to be just a Java question.  MySQL (and InnoDB) need `yyyy-mm-dd` for its `DATE` datatype.  It is up to you and Java to provide _that_ syntax.

Comment: Of course MySQL requires `yyyy-mm-dd` formatted type of  `Date`, but in my case, all I cared for is the `yyyy` part of the `Date` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Since all I need is just to extract `Subject` by `Date`, & all previous attempts kept throwing  `exceptions`,  I simply reimplementd my `dao` method like this just to make use of SQL `YEAR(DATE)` function for comparison

```
@Query(value="Select * From Subject Where YEAR(x_date) =:year", nativeQuery=true)
List<MyEntity>findByTheDate(Integer year);
```

Then my `RestController` class's method reimplemented like this

```
@GetMapping("/date")
public List<MyEntity> getByDate(@RequestParam("date")String date){

//The string passed as request param is always in the form "yyyy-mm-dd"

Integer year= Integer.parseInt(date.subString(0,4));

return dao.findByTheDate(year);
}
```

and it worked